# Scala type ascription for varargs using _* cause error

Tags: scala, syntax, types, variadic-functions

I have a rudimentary understanding of Scala varargs: that parameters to a method accepting varargs need to *hint* that it is a varargs using `_*`. Using Scala 2.10.3, I define the following two methods

```
scala> def method(varargs:Int*)(more:String*) = println(varargs,more)
method: (varargs: Int*)(more: String*)Unit
scala> val method2 = method(1,2,3)_
method2: Seq[String] => Unit =
```

Invoking them directly using a List or Range works fine

```
scala> val paramList = List("hi","ho")
paramList: List[java.lang.String] = List(hi, ho)

scala> method2(paramList)
(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3),List(hi, ho))

scala> val range = (1 to 5) map {_.toString}
range: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> method2(range)
(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3),Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Why is it when I invoke them by ascribing the parameter with `_*`, I get errors?

```
scala> method2(paramList:_*)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Seq[Seq[String]]
              method2(paramList:_*)
                      ^

scala> method2(range:_*)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]
 required: Seq[Seq[String]]
              method2(range:_*)
                      ^
```

Comment: The term is "repeated parameters" (or "params"), not "varargs."

Answer (score 8):

`method2` is not a method accepting repeated parameters, it's a function with a single parameter of type `Seq[String]`.

You should call it like this: `method2(paramList)` without `:_*`.

There is no such thing as `function accepting repeated parameters` in `scala 2.10`, but it exists in `scala 2.9`:

```
scala> def method(varargs:Int*)(more:String*) = println(varargs,more)
method: (varargs: Int*)(more: String*)Unit

scala> val method2 = method(1,2,3)_
method2: String* => Unit = <function1>

scala> val paramList = List("hi","ho")
paramList: List[java.lang.String] = List(hi, ho)

scala> method2(paramList:_*)
(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3),List(hi, ho))
```

Note the inferred type of `method2`: `Seq[String] => Unit` in `2.10` vs `String* => Unit` in `2.9`.

It wasn't a useful feature: you can't use variable of type `String* => Unit` as a parameter or return value. Actually `String* => Unit` is not a valid type even in `2.9`:

```
scala> def test(f: String* => Unit) = ()
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '=>' found.
       def test(f: String* => Unit) = ()
                           ^
```