# Scala function partial application

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I'm trying to understand how function *partial application* works in Scala.

To do that, I've built this simple code:

```
object Test extends App {
  myCustomConcat("General", "Public", "License") foreach print

  GeneralPublicLicenceAcronym(myCustomConcat(_)) foreach print

  def myCustomConcat(strings: String*): List[Char] = {
    val result = for (s <- strings) yield {
      s.charAt(0)
    }

    result.toList
  }


  def GeneralPublicLicenceAcronym (concatFunction: (String*) => List[Char] ) = {

    myCustomConcat("General", "Public", "License")
  }
}
```

***myCostumConcat*** function takes in input an array of String and it returns a list containing the first letter of each string.

So, the code

```
myCustomConcat("General", "Public", "License") foreach print
```

will print on console: **GPL**

Suppose now that I want to write a function to generate the GPL acronym, using (as input parameter) my previous function extracting the first letter of each string:

```
def GeneralPublicLicenceAcronym (concatFunction: (String*) => List[Char] ): List[Char] = {

    myCustomConcat("General", "Public", "License")
  }
```

Running this new function with partial application:

```
GeneralPublicLicenceAcronym(myCustomConcat(_)) foreach print
```

I get this error:

**Error:(8, 46) type mismatch;  found   : Seq[String]  required: String  GeneralPublicLicenceAcronym(myCustomConcat(_)) foreach  print**

Why? Can I use partial application in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is change `myCustomConcat(_)` to `myCustomConcat _`, or indeed just `myCustomConcat`

What you are doing isn't exactly partial application - it's just using a *method* as a function value.

In some cases (where a function value is expected) the compiler will work out what you mean, but in other contexts you often need to tell the compiler your intention, using the `_` suffix.

"partial application" means that we are supplying some, but  not all, of the arguments to a function, to create a new function, for example:

```
  def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y           //> add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

  val addOne: Int => Int = add(1, _)        //> addOne  : Int => Int = <function1>

  addOne(2)                                 //> res0: Int = 3
```

I suppose your case could be seen as partial application, but applying *none* of the arguments - you *can* use partial application syntax here, but you need to give a `_*` hint to the compiler because of the repeated parameters (`String*`), which ends up a bit ugly:

```
myCustomConcat(_:_*)
```

See also: [Scala type ascription for varargs using _* cause error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382694/scala-type-ascription-for-varargs-using-cause-error)